# Facebook channel.html file location

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have been looking through the documentation for the channel file, and the example code they give shows the channel file at the root of the domain

```
//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html
```

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/

http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-javascript-sdk-best-practices/58/

Does the channel.html file need to be at the root of the domain, or will it still work in a subfolder?

For instance, if I have a html page situated

```
http://WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/blah/blah/blah/index.html
```

and my channel file is situated

```
http://WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/blah/blah/blah/channel.html
```

Will it still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the channel file can be anywhere. It just need to be served by the same domain as your app, and the path you give in `FB.init` must be complete (e.g. `//www.mydomain.com/path/to/channel.html`).